# Can a grown male interact and play with his cousin's young daughter?

Tags: fiqh, practical-islam, non-mahram

Assam o Alaikum to my Muslim brothers.

My cousin has a very young daughter Masha Allah! She's barely 6 Masha Allah. Can I interact with her and lift her up and pinch her checks with affection just as most adults do to their kids? 
I understand that she is definitely my Non - Mahram by relation, but she's barely 6!
Does her immature age change the ruling of inter mingling?